# usage of "that" in the following sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, periods

Can I use *that* after the period to talk about something from the previous sentence?

For example:

> In 1995 the number of men attending art galleries was high. That number decline significantly in 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the word *that* that begins the second sentence, then certainly. It's a matter of choice (and style) whether you want to use *this* or *that*.

By the way, you missed a "d" a the end of "decline" - it should be *declined*, past tense.

Also, the two sentences do not connect smoothly, in my opinion. There is a 5 year gap between 1995 and 2000. What happened in the interim? Unless you meant that there was a *steady decline* over that 5-year period, in which case your construction should better reflect that.

Clarification: it really depends what you meant to say.

If you meant that there was a survey held every five years and that the number of gallery attendees was lower in 2000 than in 1995, then it doesn't sound right to talk about a *decline*, which generally implies a steady decrease in a quantity over time. It would be better to construct the lines like this: "In 1995, the number of men attending art galleries was high. That number *was significantly lower* in 2000."

If, on the other hand, surveys were being conducted more frequently, and you wanted to convey the idea of a steady decline between the two years, then I would instead write: "In 1995, the number of men attending art galleries was high. That number *continued to decline significantly till* 2000."

I hope that's clear enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
The example that I gave doesn't matter, I just wanted to know if using "That or This" after a full stop is valid.
but again thanks and it was more than clear :)

Comment: @MazenDraou No problem at all, glad to have helped.

Comment: I'd stick with 'the' rather than 'this' or 'that' after 'In 1995 the number of men attending art galleries was high.' 'The number of' isn't given as a specific number but rather indicates a more generalised measure ('high'). 'That' would fit better, in my opinion, after 'In 1995 the number of men attending art galleries was about two million.'